# Selenium 3.1.0 Standalone and chromedriver 2.27

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I had Selenium and Chrome working perfectly, but since last week its not working any more. This is what I get:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.1.0', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:57:44 -0800'
System info: host: 'Scs-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:8d7:2cd3:84d5:161%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.2', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:178)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:146)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler.getException(DefaultExecuteResultHandler.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.checkForError(UnixProcess.java:174)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.checkForError(CommandLine.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:179)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    ... 19 more
13:04:18.947 WARN - Exception: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
13:04:47.978 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, name=Incart Fi, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, platform=ANY}]])
13:04:47.979 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=true, name=Incart Fi, browserName=chrome, javascriptEnabled=true, platform=ANY}]
Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 29092
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Now I am wondering why, since I did not change any settings. It starts the safari browser, but there the waitForElement from nightwatch does not work. So can somebody tell me by the error why I got this issue?

```
{
  "_comment": "./selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar",
  "_comment2": "/Users/SCMacBook/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver",
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",
  "custom_commands_path" : "",
  "custom_assertions_path" : "",
  "page_objects_path" : "",
  "globals_path" : "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "/Users/SCMacBook/webdriver/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "/Users/SCMacBook/webdriver/geckodriver",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "nightwatch"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {      
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "path" : "./pics/"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true
              }
    },
    "firefox" : {
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true,
        "acceptSslCerts" : true
      }
    },  
    "safari" : {      
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "safari"
      }
    },  
    "edge" : {             
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "platform": "WIN10",       
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge"

              }
    },  
    "ie" : {        
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "platform": "WIN10",       
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "acceptSslCerts" : false

              }
    }   
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you share problematic code as well??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I did add the nightwatch.json

Comment: I am using Latest Release: ChromeDriver 2.27
Supports Chrome v54-56 and my Chrome Version is Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: Selenium 3.1.0 was released last week so you probably did change that..?

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue.  With Selenium 3.0.1 my code compiles with no issues and run perfectly.  With 3.1.0 I'm getting build errors.  I've changed nothing else except for Selenium.

Comment: @WillByers try installing the newest chromedriver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/ - my problem was pretty dumb actually. For some reason my 127.0.0.1 localhost was missing in my /etc/hosts file...

Answer (score 2):

My solution was pretty simple and I feel espacially dumb. Somehow my /etc/hosts file was changed (MAMP ? My fault ?) and the

> 127.0.0.1 localhost

part was missing. So the machine couldn't use the localhost as 127.0.0.1

Hope this helps a poor someone someday :/

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error when running a nightwatch.js test and my problem was also due to a wrong entry to the /etc/hosts file:

0.0.0.0 localhost

The error went away after the above entry was removed.

Comment: Great - so someone else will find that soon on Google and save some time :)